# Wordpress - sidebars list

Tags: wordpress, global, sidebar

I'm trying to get a list with all registered sidebars using $wp_registered_sidebars but it returns an empty array.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar)
{
    $sidebar_options[$sidebar['id']] = $sidebar['name'];
}
```

It returns Array()

In a page template it works, but not in my functions.php

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this function in your theme functions.php

```
    function get_my_widgets()
    {
    foreach ($GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar)
    {
        $sidebar_options[$sidebar['id']] = $sidebar['name'];
    }
    }

add_action('init','get_my_widgets');
```

and call this function as usual as `get_my_widgets();` to get the registered sidebar list

Answer (score 0):

add the following function in your theme functions.php

```
<?php
function my_sidebar_selectbox( $name = '', $current_value = false ) {
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;
    if ( empty( $wp_registered_sidebars ) )
        return;
     foreach ( $wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar ) :
     echo $sidebar['name'];
     endforeach; 

}
?>
```

and call it as `my_sidebar_selectbox();` it is working to me